How do we feel about employees of contracting/consulting firms including links to their employer in their answers?
I've been seeing more people linking to their employers recently:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/425029/24889
All of the remaining answers by this particular user (they've been consistently edited out by the community, look at the edit history to confirm) and this deleted answer of theirs too

These examples are generally at least half-decent answers, certainly better than the people who just plug their blog and don't give the answer here on this site, but the clear effort to attempt to drive people to their employer/service rubs me the wrong way.
How does everyone else feel about this?

Allow it as long as the bulk of the answer is relevant and helpful?
Edit it out and hope we don't get into dueling edits?
Edit it out and encourage them to keep it in their profile?
Some other approach?


Personally, I lean towards option 3 as I do think that it should be edited out and only included on their profile. I have a similar feeling about the attempts to drive services, as in my mind it goes against the purpose of this site. I'd caveat this with the obvious statement that if editing our the driving of traffic/services to their employer removes the usefulness of the answer then it should just be straight up deleted.

I feel like the same as Callum on this - there's no doubt that the content in the answer is helpful in some way, but just tacking on the company at the end like that is basically just advertising their services. It'd be different if they were linking through to a blog post with more detail about the topic, but saying "if you need help with X contact us" is really no different to 99% of the messages I get on LinkedIn minus the ficticious email cain.
